# Replicate changes to all instances in instance group

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling, multiple-instances

I want to create autoscalable instance group with load balancer in Google cloud platform. Since workload is prestashop site hence need to update content regularly. Is it possible to replicate updates in one instance to all others in same group (something like master slave node) such that even newly created instances have those updates?

Is there an way that changing data in one instance update it in other instances of managed instance group?

Thanks and Regards

Rishi

Answer (score 0):

Managed instance groups are created and upheld by their instance template. Each instance will be configured based off of the configuration of the template. It will not replicate updates from one instance to another or automatically replicate the data that is put on one instance to the others.

I would suggest to go to the [following page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) that explains which scenarios are best to use a managed instance group.